# Homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z} $ and $\mathbb{Z} _2 $

Tags: group-homomorphism, free-product

What does a homomorphism between the free product $\mathbb{Z} \star \mathbb{Z} $ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 $ look like? I'm having trouble trying to do anything with this.

Comment: What do you know about the free product?  For example, are you familiar with its universal property?

Comment: Can't say I know much. I am familiar with the universal property, but how does this help.

Comment: For groups $G$, $H$, and $K$, the universal property gives a complete description of homomorphisms $G * H \to K$ in terms of homomorphisms $G \to K$ and $H \to K$.  I assume you can list all homomorphisms $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/2$, so this should allow you to list all homomorphisms $\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/2$.

Answer (score -1):

Think about the epimorphism $\Bbb Z\rightarrow \Bbb Z_2: x\mapsto x\mod 2$.

For $\Bbb Z^2\rightarrow\Bbb Z_2$ there are two obvious possibilities

$(x,y)\mapsto x+y \mod 2$ and $(x,y)\mapsto x\cdot y \mod 2$

since $\mod n$, $n\geq 2$, is a congruence relation, i.e. compatible with the operations of addition and multiplication.